# The Subspace of Polynomials of Degree ≤ n

Tags: linear-algebra

Example:
The degree of a polynomial is the highest power of the variable that occurs with a nonzero coefficient. It is not true that the set W of polynomials with positive degree n is a subspace of F(−∞, ∞) because that set is not closed under addition. For example, the polynomials

$1+2x+3x^2$ and $5+7x-3x^2$

both have degree 2, but their sum has degree 1. **What is true, however, is that for each nonnegative integer n the polynomials of degree n or less form a subspace of F(−∞, ∞)**. We will denote this space by $P_n$.

The part I don't understand is that I thought every polynomial with a degree of 2 or less is a subspace. The part in bold is what's confusing me, when is a polynomial a subspace?

Comment: What is your question? Of course $P_2$ is a vector space, as you said in bold face. "Every polynomial with a degree of 2 or less" is not a vector space. "is every vector less than or equal to degree 2 a vector space or not?" No, a vector is also no vector space, except for the zero vector.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You mean, "is a vector space"?

Comment: @TheoBendit What "is a vector space"? A "vector less than or equal to degree 2"? No.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah yes, I see what you're saying.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I had to rewrite the question because I confused myself. In the example shown, the textbook says that isn't a subspace because it's not closed under addition. But I thought every polynomial with degree 2 or less is a subspace?

Comment: @chubberson The point is, the set of polynomials of a fixed degree is not closed under addition. Moreover, it doesn't even include the $0$ vector. However, $P_n$ is a subspace. It contains the $0$ vector, the sum of two polynomials of degree at most $n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ (how would an $x^{n+1}$ or higher order term even appear?), and it's closed under scalar multiplication. Indeed, you can just view $P_n$ as the span of the vectors $(1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n)$, and spans are automatically subspaces!

Comment: A single polynomial cannot be a subspace. A subspace (of the space of polynomials) is a *subset* (of the space of polynomials) subject to certain conditions (like closed under addition and scalar multiplication). This. Seems to be the most pressing confusion you have. It is NOT pedantry.